# Don't alert AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm trying to get result and alert it if the solicitude was successful or not on the PHP file, it worked (because changed the results) but the AJAX didn't show alerts (No error and no "true")

js:

```
function addentrys() {
    var nwentry =  {};
    el = document.getElementById('addname').value;
    eldmn = document.getElementById('adddomain').value;
    nwentry.name = el;
    nwentry.domain = eldmn;

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'api/domain',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: nwentry
    }).done(function(data) {
        alert(data);
    });
}
```

php:

```
    $app->post('/domain', function () {
    $jsonContents = file_get_contents('data/data.json');
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $domain = $_POST['domain'];
    $data = json_decode($jsonContents, true);
    $last_item = end($data);
    $last_item_id = $last_item['id'];
    $data[] = array(
        'name' => $name,
        'domain' => $domain,
        'id' => $last_item_id+1
    );


    $json = json_encode($data);
    file_put_contents('data/data.json', $json);
    return true;
});
```

Comment: Any console errors?

Comment: So add `.fail()` and see what you got

Comment: @Justinas no errors

Comment: @epascarello where I have to add it?

Comment: To the ajax call... http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#jqXHR

Comment: Your PHP code seems to only write to a file, but not produce any response output, it only returns true. You are trying to display “data” on the client, that you neglected to output on the server side in the first place ... d’uh!

Comment: @Cbroe and How can I produce a response?

Comment: @Cbroe Yeah but what I have to put into ECHO?

Comment: Usually you would create a small JSON object containing something like a `status` property, that then gets assigned either true or false, so that your client-side code can then check for that status.

Comment: Can you write it on an answer? And show me an example pls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result is probably not in JSON format, so when jQuery tries to parse it as such, it fails. You can catch the error with error: callback function.

You don't seem to need JSON in that function anyways, so you can also take out the dataType: 'json' row.

Comment: The first part was right, it wasn't JSON and when I encoded it it works, but the second I didn't take out nothing, so thx